# How to get the directory part of current URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, redirect, directory

I'm trying to add a "back to dir" button at the top of a web page, which would redirect the user to the same URL, but with no filename in it.

For example, clicking that button while viewing the URL

http://example.com/somedir/button.html

would redirect you to the

http://example.com/somedir/

So I've created the following code:

```
<html>
<body>

<input type="button"
value="back to dir"
onclick="top.location=document.URL.replace(/[^\\]*$/, '')">

</body>
</html>
```

but I'm missing the correct code, which would shave away the filename from the current URL in `document.URL`

Does anybody have a good idea here please?

Here is the JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/afarber/PERBY/

And I'd prefer not to use jQuery this one time.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this `document.URL.substr(0,document.URL.lastIndexOf('/'))`

It will work for sure!

Comment: Thanks, this looks good - event better than my regex (where I made a typo...)

Comment: You are welcome, vote it up if it works good, so that other people can get benefit from it.

Comment: This doesn't work if the current url ends in a trailing slash, as it so often does.

Answer (score 4):

This one-liner also works:

```
document.URL.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')
```

Comment: While this method works it is much slower then the string solution posted by @abdul-rauf

Answer (score 4):

```js
console.log(new URL(document.URL));
```

you would get all object like this :

```
{
  href:"https://yy.xx.id/index.php/5351/user/private/images%20%282%29.jpeg?forcedownload=1",

  origin:"https://smi.kerjaindonesia.id", 
  protocol: "https:", 
  username: "", 
  password: "", 
  pathname: "index.php/5351/user/private/images%20%282%29.jpeg"  ,
  port: "" ,
  protocol: "https:",
  search: "?forcedownload=1"
}
```

Comment: Best solution and not hacky! You could also access these parameters and some extra ones from `window.location`, such as `window.location.hostname`

Answer (score 1):

```
/* to avoid query parameters, use pathname instead of href */
var l = document.location.pathname.split('/');
l.pop();
console.log(document.location.origin + l.join('/'));
```

Comment: FYI: `document.location` is deprecated, use `window.location` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The following gets directories, including the case where the last character is a slash.

```
document.URL.replace(/\/[^/]+\/?$/, '');
```

This effectively states the following (assuming they can be found in this order)

1. `\/`: Find a "/"
2. `[^/]+`: Find one or more characters after it that are not "/"
3. `\/?`: Find an optional "/" after those character(s)
4. `$`: Find the end of the string

Then remove these by `''`, so we're left with the directory only.

Again, this assumes there *is* a slash present marking a directory and that this is not just a URL where the only slashes are within `http://`.

Comment: I modified this to keep any path component with a trailing slash (so a URL that's already a directory stays unchanged): `window.location.href.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '/')`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, which takes into account both when the URL ends in a trailing slash and when it doesn't:

```
var currUrl = document.URL,
    newUrl;
if (currUrl.charAt(currUrl.length - 1) === '/') {
    newUrl = currUrl.slice(0, currUrl.lastIndexOf('/'));
    newUrl = newUrl.slice(0, newUrl.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/';
} else {
    newUrl = currUrl.slice(0, currUrl.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/';
}
console.log(newUrl);
```