# How to get the value in url with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, url

How can I get the value in the url using jquery in my wordpress theme footer.php?

I'm using the following code to get url

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

And the result I get is www.example.com/2016/ and the value I want to get from this url is 2016 what is the next step to get the number 2016 from the url?

Comment: Sorry, wrong duplicate  - here is a better one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984943/how-to-get-the-directory-part-of-current-url-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming an input of `http://www.example.com/2016/` (as it would appear if you use `window.location` to retrieve it) then you can `split()` the URL by the `/` character and retrieve the values from the resulting array. Try this:

```js
var url = 'http://www.example.com/2016/'; // use window.location
var urlArray = url.split('/');
var year = urlArray[3];

console.log(year);
```

Comment: Not worth looking for a dupe?