# How can I get just a directory from the URL in Javascript, omitting the domain?

Tags: javascript

I have a domain name that looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/abc/xyz/something_something
```

Or sometimes just:

```
http://www.example.com/abc/
```

In either case want to get *just* the `abc` part. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985051/184108), which suggests the following code:

```
document.URL.substr(0,document.URL.lastIndexOf('/'))
```

Which returns:

```
http://www.example.com/abc/xyz/
```

How can I extend the above code to extract out *only* the first directory name?

Note that it's *always* the first directory after the domain name, and the directory is always a 3 letter code.

Comment: You might wanna start by switching out `document.URL` with `location.pathname`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the path with:

```
window.location.pathname // "/questions/45956695/how-can-i-get-just-a-directory-from-the-url-in-javascript-omitting-the-domain#"
```

Then split out the first parameter:

```js
// (Can't use window.location in snippets)
var pathname = "/questions/45956695/how-can-i-get-just-a-directory-from-the-url-in-javascript-omitting-the-domain#"

var p = pathname.split('/')[1]
console.log(p);
```

Comment: (on `https://www.stackoverflow.com`, `location.pathname` equals `"/"`, for which this will return an empty string.)

Comment: @evolutionxbox He sure can, but since Stack Overflow often is used to find a complete solution to a question and use that in other projects. In that case it is useful to have an example that does not throw an exception. In this case Cerbrus is right, that this array always has 2 elements so it is a complete answer after all. :)

Comment: @Ivar: I wouldn't cover all kinds of corner cases in an SO answer. Stick to the question, and if there are other criteria, the OP will have to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Substring location.pathname

```
location.pathname.substring(1,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression:

```
const str = 'http://www.example.com/abc/xyz/something_something'
const match = str.match(/https?\:\/\/[a-z.]+\/([a-z0-9]+)\/?/)
// match[1] === 'abc'
```